# jQuery datatable if data length greater than certain length

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I once used PHP to print my datatables.  When I got to a particular column that had a string greater than 17 characters, I would use the following to print ellipses after the 17th character:

```
if(strlen($row[tli]) > 17){echo "<td><a href='#'>".substr(row['number'],0,17)."..."</a></td>";}
```

I need to do the same thing using ajax instead.

```
$('#example1').DataTable({      
  "ajax": {
    "url": "api/displayQnams.php",
    "type": "POST",
    "dataSrc": ''
  },
  "columns": [
    {
      "data": "number",
      "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol)
      {
        if(oData.number.length > 17) // here is where the initial check starts
        {$(nTd).html("<a href='#'>'"+oData.number+"...'</a>")} // here is where it should print the ellipses after the 17th character
        else
        {$(nTd).html("<a href='#'>'"+oData.number+"'</a>"}
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

oData.number.length gives me the following error in the console:

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

What am I missing to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was some of the oData was null, and you cannot compare null value using length.  So I created a variable and if oData.number was null, set the variable to ''.

Here is how I got it to work:

```
"fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol)
{
  if(oData.tli == null || oData.tli == ""){var tlinumber = '';}
  else{var tlinumber = oData.tli;}
  if(tlinumber.length > 17)
  {
    $(nTd).html("<a href='#'>'"+tlinumber.substring(0, 17)+"...'</a>")
  }
  else
  {
    $(nTd).html("<a href='#'>'"+tlinumber+"'</a>"
  }
}
```